# Python: Square Brackets Inside of Parentheses

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I saw **square bracketed arguments inside of parentheses**. I don't know what it means and how it differs from a normal argument, so I am hoping for some enlightenment on this matter.

### Here are the code lines in question:

<sub>(I'll print the whole block since someone might find it useful but the important parts are ***line 3 of the first code snippet*** and ***line 2 of the second code snippet***)</sub>

#### First case:

```py
def __additional_cards(self, player):
    while not player.is_busted() and player.is_hitting():
        self.deck.deal([player])
        print(player)
        if player.is_busted():
            player.bust()
```

The bracketed argument in this line represents an object of a `Player` class (there can be many players) for the game and the code's purpose is to deal an additional card if the player asks for it.

#### Second case:

```py
def play(self):
    self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)
    self.dealer.flip_first_card()    # hide dealer's first card
    for player in self.players:
        print(player)
    print(self.dealer)
```

In this case, the method `.deal` is used to deal starting cards to all of the players in the game as well as to the dealer. Here's the code for the `.deal` method for reference:

```py
def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
   for rounds in range(per_hand):
         for hand in hands:
            if self.cards:
                top_card = self.cards[0]
                self.give(top_card, hand)
```

As you can see, it only takes 1 argument as to which 'hands' the cards should be dealt with, but the code above adds the dealer with the command `+ [self.dealer]` and this is something I see for the first time.

Is the dealer added to hands simply by the `+` and if so, why is it in square brackets?

The code is taken from Michael Dawson's book, *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, 3rd Edition* and it is a section where he teaches OOP by explaining how to make a simple game of Blackjack.

Comment: `self.deck.deal([player])` creates a list with 1 element and passes that to the `deal` function.

Comment: `self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)` combines two lists into one and passes that to the `deal` function. (Assuming `self.players` is a list).

Comment: Deal needs to know the count of players, and since deal is expecting hands to be an array, you are creating and passing an inline array into the function.  So in your example, you will deal 1 hand, for `player`

Comment: Always note that square brackets `[`, `]` in **Python** are basically used for **2** purposes. The primary use is for creating a list and the secondary use is in case of accessing **tuples**, **dictionaries**, **sets**, **lists** etc. In your code, in 1st case, you're passing **dictionary** as an actual argument in function call. In 2nd case, you're concatenating 2 **lists**.

Answer (score 3):

The method `deck.deal()` takes as an argument a list of people to deal to. You cannot pass it a single object, because the method probably loops through every object in the list passed in a deals to those people. When you input `[player]`, you're telling it the only person to deal to is that single `player`. It's good to leave it as a list because it allows you to generalize the code to accept an arbitrary number of people to deal to.

Looking at `self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)`, what is happening here is we're adding the dealer to the list of the people being dealt to. Again, deal takes in a list of people, and since we want to deal to all the current players and the dealer we can just combine those two things into a single list. `self.players` is probably just a list of all the people who are playing, and when we `+ [self.dealer]` we create a new list that has all of the players and the dealer. Python has operator overloading, meaning we can "add" two lists to combine them into a single longer list.

If I was coding this, I would just make `player` always be a list itself and `self.dealer` always be a single element list, since the code is generalized to only accept lists it seems.

EDIT for clarification:

I imagine the method `deal` looks something like:

```
def deal(people):
    '''
    people = a list of person objects to deal to
    '''
    for person in people:
        # do something to that person
```

`player` is just an instance of an object. If we want to deal to ONLY that person, we need to pass in `player` in a list: `[player]` otherwise the code to deal to an arbitrary number of people would break, since you cannot loop over the `player` object, only a list of people.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, this is insightful. However, regarding the ([player])...
You and others said that it's formatted like that so that the deal is passed to a single player but, 'player' is already an iteration of a single object from the 'players' list so, maybe it's not formatted like that for those reasons. Or, I might be misinterpreting something.

Comment: If you run `type(player)` it should return that it is an instance of some object, I'm guessing.

see my edit above.